# 19.10 MacBook Air '11 Brightness Control not working

Tags: grub2, brightness, macbook, macbook-air

I have updated my Ubuntu since Dec 2019. I am running it on MacBook Air 2011, but when I tried to change my brightness to lower. It isn't a working function. I tried to update on my grub `/etc/default/grub` and added this `acpi_backlight=vendor` at the end in 5th line of grub codes. This is what I updated and reboot my MacBook Air:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I am running Ubuntu as primary OS on MacBook, not virtualbox or anything:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

Comment: @K7AAY -- it is now updated.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. You can't change brightness by pressing the brightness key combination? Have you tried manually changing the value of `/sys/class/backlight/?/brightness`?

Comment: @Quasímodo -- I went to this directory but I don't have any files in `/sys/class/backlight/` because it is empty.